# Alert Dialogs Over Activity Transitions

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Assuming we have two Activities: List Activity and Detail Activity.

We have a "Save" button in Detail Activity which after saving, finishes the activity to go back to the List Activity.

I would like to know if we can have an alert dialog fired from "Save" function of Detail Activity so that it can stay over the transition of moving back to List Activity..

In other words, Can a Dialog exist outside the Activity? My understanding is that a Dialog is a child of an Activity and has to be destroyed if the activity is destroyed..

In iOS this is possible since the Dialogs are attached to the navigation controllers. Is this possible in Android? I am not considering fragments here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to display a message like "your changes have been saved" then in the Android world you would display a [Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html). A Toast can even have a custom layout.

Another possibility would be to move your code to [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) (which would be a good idea anyway) and then have an activity that acts as controller (i.e. creates and swaps the fragments). That should allow you to open a dialog while activating a different fragment.

Comment: Ahh, I completely forgot about the Toast. That would be the best solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose two possible options:

- You can stop the AlertDialog when the Detail Activity  is dismmissed and then show it again in the method `onCreate` on the List Activity.
- Another option is that you use a one single activity rather than two activities, and change the layout of the Detail Activity to the layout of the List Activity when you push the "Save" button.

There isn't an easier way to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks Adri, Toast was the better option in my scenario. Appreciate your answer too.